# ROLLBACK Rails and ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have the following piece of code:

```
def store_or_update_agent(agent)
  existing_agent = Agent.find_by_slug(agent['slug'])
  if !existing_agent
logger.info('No record found, creating one')
    logger.info(agent)
    new_agent = Agent.new(agent)
    new_agent.save
  else
logger.info('Existing agent')
    existing_agent.update(agent)
  end
end
```

This is used to process rows from a spreadsheet I am importing using RubyXL. RubyXL is doing its job fine, and the logger info tells me that the rows are imported properly. The problem however is that only one row is getting saved to the DB. It's not the first, nor the last, but somewhere near the end.

When Look in my log for the record prior to the one that got saved, and the one that got saved, I see something like this:

This is for the record that does not get saved:

```
No record found, creating one
{"first"=>"John", "last"=>"Doe", .....}
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  ROLLBACK
```

This is for the record that gets saved:

```
No record found, creating one
{"first"=>"John", "last"=>"Doe", .....}  
[1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
[1m[36mSQL (41.1ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `agents` (`first`, `last`) VALUES ('John','Doe')[0m
[1m[35m (21.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
```

Any ideas what's going on here, and what the ROLLBACK Is for?

Comment: `ROLLBACK` basically means to back out a transaction.  The opposite of `COMMIT`.  When a `ROLLBACK` gets sent to the database, all the changes since the last `COMMIT` (which are all the changes in the current transaction, essentially) are backed out.

Comment: Hmmm, yes, but why is ActiveRecord deciding to roll back for one record and not another, using the same piece of code (the one I have in my question)

Comment: Is there any difference between the data it's trying to insert between the first and second case?  Can you output the actual SQL statements being issued for each case?  Are there any differences?

Comment: Yes, there are differences in the data. Unfortunately, I cannot post the actual data. Could it be the character set? I did not think that Rails 4 Active Record has an issue dealing with unicode, and why am I not getting a more descriptive error (what's causing the rollback)

Comment: What is making you think it's the character set?  Are there unusual characters in the failing data record that there isn't in the passing ones?

Comment: Unicode means multibyte support for characters. There is nothing unusual about unicode characters. The same character would look the same using different character set.

Comment: That's not what I asked.  I asked whether there are any unusual characters in the failing record that isn't in the passing one?

Comment: No there are no unusual characters and that would have been the first thing I checked